# Overfull boxes in Memoir Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, tocloft

I am trying to address overfull boxes in my thesis table of contents.  I am using the memoir class in draft mode to mark the two problems.  This starts out minor (MWE doesn't look too bad) but grows worse with more pages.  I am certain that setting a magical flag (perhaps via the `tocloft` package?) will solve each problem, but I am not able to determine what the flag should be.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,draft]{memoir}
\usepackage{fullpage}         % use entire page
\usepackage{tocloft}

\settocdepth{subsection}      % Include subsections in TOC
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}   % Number subsections in body and TOC

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents} % Change Contents name

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage

\mainmatter

\part{Part I}

\part{Part II}

\part{Part III}

\part{Part IV}

\backmatter

\appendix

\part*{Appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image: TOC with overfull boxes]

Comment: Thanks Brent. I thought my magical flag was something low-level but I see it is all defined by `memoir` (or `tocloft` I suppose).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memoir includes the functionality of `tocloft` so there's no need to load it. Use the `memoir` macros for setting the TOC parameters.  In this case you need to set the width of the page number and the right margin in the TOC, and the width of the part numbers.

I've added the following to your code:

```
\setpnumwidth{3em}
\setrmarg{4em}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{3em}
```

Adjust these as you see fit.  For section numbers etc. you may also need to adjust the width, using the appropriate length, for example:

```
\setlength{\cftsectionnumwidth}{...}
```

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,draft]{memoir}
\usepackage{fullpage}         % use entire page

\setpnumwidth{3em}
\setrmarg{4em}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{3em}

\settocdepth{subsection}      % Include subsections in TOC
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}   % Number subsections in body and TOC

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents} % Change Contents name

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage
\listoftables\clearpage

\mainmatter

\part{Part I}

\part{Part II}

\part{Part III}

\part{Part IV}

\backmatter

\appendix

\part*{Appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Perfect, thanks Alan!  This has been bothering me for months.  I also set `\cftchapternumwidth` to match `\cftpartnumwidth`.